# stackexchangeのAPI接続でApplication Login Failureになる

Tags: api, oauth, stackexchange-api

StackExchange APIに接続できません
どうすればいいのでしょうか?

最初にブラウザから`https://stackexchange.com/oauth`に色々なクエリをつけてリクエストを出し、`Approve`ボタンを押すと、下記のエラーが発生します

```
Application Login Failure

An error occurred while login into an application.
Error Details

error description: Cannot return to provided redirect_uri
```

redirect_uriは`http://127.0.0.1:8000/redirect`にしています
私はOauth Domainを`localhost (127.0.0.1:8000)`にしています
この方法で認証する場合にはドメインを持ったWebサーバが必要になるのでしょうか?

Comment: localhostに返しているのはデスクトップなどローカルなアプリケーション単体で使うからでしょうか

Comment: はい、そうです。
やはりデスクトップなどの場合はimplicit flowで認証しなければいけないのでしょうか?

Comment: ドキュメントに"redirect_uri - must be under an apps registered domain"ってある上に、client_id取得時にOAuth用のドメインを聞いてくるのでexplicitではドメインがいる様な気がします。
implicitはデスクトップ単体でできるとありますがexplictにする理由はなにかあるのでしょうか。

Comment: WebExtension(ブラウザ拡張機能)でも使おうと考えているのですが、その場合はどちらにすればいいのでしょうか?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web Extensionでしたら[ドキュメント](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication)のデスクトップで使う場合の手順でいけると思います。implicit flow（`https://stackexchange.com/oauth/dialog`）で`redirect_url`を`https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success`にすれば、リダイレクト後アドレスのハッシュにアクセストークンが入るはずです。
またWeb ExtensionならStack Exchangeが提供している[Javascriptのライブラリ](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/js-lib)が使えると思います。認証の機能しか無いので、inboxへのアクセスなどは自分でAPIを打たないといけませんが。

---

追記
ブラウザで以下のアドレスにアクセスすると（idは伏せてます）

```
https://stackexchange.com/oauth/dialog?client_id=1234&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fstackexchange.com%2Foauth%2Flogin_success
```

承認するか確認され、承認後以下のアドレスに期待通り飛ばされました。

```
https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success#access_token=aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa&expires=12345
```

StackAppでの設定：
 - OAuth Domain： `stackexchange.com`
 - [x] Enable Client Side OAuth Flow
 - [ ] Disable Desktop Application OAuth Redirect Uri

Web Extensionでしたらこれをbackgroundページ内の`iframe`などでやればいけると思います。

---

追記
backgroundページではログインできないのでダメですね...

```
chrome.windows.create({'url': '...', 'type': 'popup'}, function(window) {
    ...
});
```

とかでポップアップを表示を表示して、URL移動を検知するって感じでいけそうな気はしますが試してません。